# Unable to pass HTML data into Code.gs function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I click on the run button (See my HTML code), I am unable to paste the data into sheet.

When I run the makeRequest function from the editor, I get an error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'startDate' of undefined.

HTML

```
<div class="block form-group">

        <label for="select">Date Range</label>
        <select id="select">
            <option selected id="default" value="default">None</option>
            <option selected id="today" value="today">Today</option>
            <option selected id="yesterday" value="yesterday">Yesterday</option>
            
        </select>

 <div class="form-group">
 <button id="btn">Run it</button>  
 </div>       
</div>
```

Javascript. HTML

```
<script>

  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click",retrieveFacebookData);
  

  function retrieveFacebookData () {

    var facebookAccountData = {};
    //I will be adding more key value pairs in this object later

    facebookAccountData.startDate = document.getElementById('select').value;
    
    
    google.script.run.makeRequest(facebookAccountData);
    

  }

    
</script>
```

Code.gs

```
function makeRequest(facebookAccountData) {
 
  console.log(facebookAccountData.startDate);

  const row = [facebookAccountData.startDate,newDate()];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow(row);

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- From `When I run the makeRequest function from the editor, I get an error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'startDate' of undefined.`, in this case, if you directly run `makeRequest` with the script editor, the argument of `facebookAccountData` is not declared. By this, such error occurs. In your script, it is required to run the Javascript at the sidebar, dialog and Web Apps.
- About your HTML & Javasript side, I think that there is a modification point. In your Javascript, `document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click",retrieveFacebookData);` is used. But `<button class="btn">Run it</button>` has no ID.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script 1:

When you want to directly run the function of `makeRequest` with the script editor, how about the following modification?

```
function makeRequest(facebookAccountData) {
  facebookAccountData = {startDate: "sample"};

  console.log(facebookAccountData.startDate);
  const row = [facebookAccountData.startDate, "newDate()"];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow(row);
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

When you want to run the function of `makeRequest` with HTML & Javascript side, how about the following modification?

##### Google Apps Script side:

```
function openDialog() {
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "sample");
}

function makeRequest(facebookAccountData) {
  console.log(facebookAccountData.startDate);
  const row = [facebookAccountData.startDate, "newDate()"];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow(row);
}
```

##### HTML & Javascript side: `index.html`

```
<div class="block form-group"> <label for="select">Date Range</label> <select id="select">
<option selected id="default" value="default">None</option>
<option selected id="today" value="today">Today</option>
<option selected id="yesterday" value="yesterday">Yesterday</option>
</select>
  <div class="form-group"> <button id="btn">Run it</button> </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click",retrieveFacebookData);

  function retrieveFacebookData () {
    var facebookAccountData = {};
    //I will be adding more key value pairs in this object later
    facebookAccountData.startDate = document.getElementById('select').value;
    google.script.run.makeRequest(facebookAccountData);
  }
</script>
```

- In this case, please run `openDialog()` with the script editor. By this, a dialog is opened and HTML can be seen. When you select it and click the button, `makeRequest` is run with `facebookAccountData`. By this, the value is appended to the Spreadsheet.

#### Reference:

- [Dialogs and Sidebars in Google Workspace Documents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)

Comment: This work well. I can see the data pasted into my sheet. One last question, how can I map the variable into an end point: const endpoint = 'XXX/insights?date_preset=facebookAccountData.startDate  ? Something like this?